# How to fix 'TypeError: resolveData(...).map is not a function' for ReactTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display Api json data in React Table.

I tried using different tables and the only one which was `react-json-to-table` but I am unable to css the table. So I am using react table which comes with css, and this error occurred.

```js
class GetStudents extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          students: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount()
    { 
        const url="http://127.0.0.1:8081/endpoint/students";
        fetch(url,{
            method:"GET"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(students=>{
            this.setState({students:students})
        })
    }
    render() { 

        const columns=[
        {
           Header:"Name",
           accessor:"studentName"
        } ,  
        {
            Header:"Surname",
            accessor:"studentSurname"
        } ,  
        {
            Header:"Grade",
            accessor:"studentGrade"
        } ,  
        ]

        return (   

               <div className="tbl" >
                    <ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.students}> 
                    </ReactTable>
                </div> 
        );    
    } 

}

export default GetStudents;
```

I expect the output of api json values in table but actual output is:

> error 1: TypeError: resolveData(...).map is not a function
>   ReactTable.getDataModel
>
> error 2: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): resolveData(...).map is not a function

Comment: can you show me the ReactTable code? or the sandbox.

Comment: I say just change `ReactTable` to be a self closing tag `<ReactTable />` and see if you are unintentionally passing `resolveData` as null etc. see this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#props

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here,

```
.then(accounts =>{
   this.setState({students:students})
})
```

You need to set `accounts` in state,

```
.then(accounts =>{
   this.setState({students:accounts})
})
```

---

**Update**

You need to conditionally render your table, because `componentDidMount` executes after first render and initially `this.state.students` id `[]` (empty array), so you got error.

```
<div className="tbl" >
 {
    this.state.students.length > 0 ?
     <ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.students}></ReactTable>
     :
     <div>Loading...</div>
 }
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the wrong state:

I think this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/endpoint/students";
  fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(accounts => {
      this.setState({
        students: students
      })
    })
}
```

Should be

```
componentDidMount() {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/endpoint/students";
  fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(accounts => {
      this.setState({
        students: accounts
      })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is update your default state from `[]` to something like -

```
state = [{
studentName: '',
studentSurname: '',
studentGrade: 'N/A'
}]
```

The reason for this suggestion is -

1. From the error, it looks like method `resolveData` of `ReactTable` is mapping `data` and `columns`.
2. During the initial render, you don't have data for students in state, `resolveData` is called with empty data and columns with accessor set.
3. The resolve data could not map `columns` with empty `data` and returned undefined.
4. On `undefined` data, you can't call `map` method of `Array`.

> > With the default state updated, initially you would see default values. When actual `students` data is available in the state, you shouldn't see that error.